# Can't use IplImage with OpenCV 2.4.4

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, iplimage

I have just downloaded and installed the new opencv version. The fact that it natively supports java is quite exiting. However I am having some trouble porting my javacv code over. I can no longer seem to use IplImage as it can not be resolved, even though I have imported org.opencv.core.*; Switching to Mat does not seem ideal as many of the opencv functions that I use require an IplImage.

Example:

```
public static IplImage getAbsDifference (IplImage source1, IplImage source2){

        IplImage result = cvCreateImage(new CvSize(source1.width(),source1.height()),source1.depth(),3);

        cvAbsDiff(source1, source2, result);

        return result;

    }
```

So what kind of changes do I need to make to my old code for it to work with the new version of opencv for java?

Sorry if this is a noobish question, still new to the image processing field.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of answers, and my own inability to find it myself, I recommend you to do the same I'm doing: Use JavaCV https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

From what I've learned, it seems that OpenCV's own support of Java was recent, while JavaCV seems to have been around for longer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer: Do the change from IplImage to Mat.

It seems many functions are implemented for Mats (at least in Java), like find/drawContour http://docs.opencv.org/java/index-all.html